# How to show postgresql expression type?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to show any expression type name.
Something like 'type' function in python.

To work somewhat like these:

```
select type(1);
'int'

select type(ROW(1, 'abc'));
'row(int, text)'

select type(select * from t1);
'setof t1'
```

Is there anything like this in postgresql?

Answer (score 21):

It's called [`pg_typeof()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html) although it's not exactly what you want

```
select pg_typeof(1), ROW(1, 'abc');
```

Returns

```
pg_typeof | row    
----------+--------
integer   | (1,abc)
```

You can't however use  `pg_typeof(select * from t1)`, not even with a `limit 1` because the function requires a single expression as its input, not multiple columns. You could however do something like: `pg_typeof((select some_column from t1))`